# How to perform search operation on data received from WebService?

Tags: ios, web-services, uitableview, uisearchbar

How to perform Search operation on data received from WebService?

I have a service which gets all the information from the database. I want to perform search operation on the data received from the service which is displayed in custom tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert json data to NSArray or NSMutableArray then use NSPredicate to search in that array for example you have an array myArray with key value pairs

```
myArray:[ 
 dict1:{
    name: "abc";
    id: "12";
    }
  dict2:{
    name: "cde";
    id: "13";
    }
]
```

now you need the objects having name as abc, then use

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = 'abc'"];
[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
```

it will return you the filtered array

Answer (score 0):

Generally the response from webservice is in Json or XML format. you can convert that json response in your MutableArray format and then use a NSPredicate to filter your Data.

here is the good article for How to use NSPredicates,
http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/